SharePoint online list form PowerApp shows edit link when user only has read permissions
I have a custom list with a form edited in PowerApps. I have users with only read permissions. They can not edit items by clicking the context menu from the item or using the commandbar from the list. This is expected behavior. When they click on the list item title the item is shown in read mode in the PowerApp.

In the PowerApp there is a link shown called "Edit all". When a user with only read permissions clicks on this link the PowerApp is changed to edit mode. When a users edits some fields and pushes the save button an error is shown after closing and opening the item.

Why is the "Edit all" link visible when a user only has read permissions?

I think this issue is not related to Power Apps. "Edit all" option is default functionality of SharePoint which should NOT be visible for users with READ permissions. Try raising support ticket with Microsoft and report this behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

in the app you can remove this 'Edit All' button. Or set the button's 'Visible' parameter true of false according the user state (if you can tell about the logged in user whether he/she should have edit permission or not).
The other and the main problem (which I faced lately, so I think it a new bug), that this is the behavior in Sharepoint as well (it looks like you can edit things, until you try to save your edits which causes error).

The edit all is not present when you edit the app. It's added during runtime when you open the app from SharePoint to display/edit an item.
